# UI rendering error after upgrading to Angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript, angular13

This error started after I upgraded my angular project from 12 to 13.

I have the following in my template:

```
<input [formControlName]="a.no" [value]="this.someFunction(question.no)" (change)="someOtherfunction(question.no,$event)"/>
```

The problem is in the Chrome browser, I don't get to see the value. If I downgrade, I works again.

In my IDE, I have the message everywhere for reactive form.

*Property formControlName is not provided by any applicable directives nor by input element*

Comment: what about other code? Is input inside formGroup? And reactiveFormsModule imported?

Comment: yes, the structure is properly implemented